# Different transition delays for added class and hover effect

Tags: css, css-transitions

So basically I have four div boxes, which appear when a class is added through javascript. They appear with a transition-delay so they don't arrive at the same time when the class is added. This is done through this code:

```
&.active {

       @for $i from 1 through 4 {
            &:nth-last-child(#{$i}n) {
                transition-delay: #{($i * 0.07) - 0.07}s;
                opacity: 1.0;
            }                
        }

        &:hover {
            transform: scale(1.20);
            transition: all 0.2s ease-out; 
    }
}
```

So when the `.active` class is added the divs goes from `opacity: 0.0` to `opacity: 1.0` with a `transition-delay`. This works as intended. However, when I do the hover effect this delay is also present on the individual divs. So the first hover is quick, and the rest is delayed etc.

I am not entirely sure how to fix this. Can I somehow "delete" the transition-delay after, or...?

Comment: Do you mean `&` **`:not(:hover)`** `:nth-last-child(#{$i}n)`?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I needed !
Feel free to make an answer, and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want to prevent the delay effects just when the element is being hovered, what you can do is add `:not(:hover)` to your original selector that adds the `transition-delay`. Replace your original selector:

```
&:nth-last-child(#{$i}n)
```

with:

```
&:not(:hover):nth-last-child(#{$i}n)
```